# How to pad a one hot array of length n with a 1 on either side of the 1

Tags: arrays, numpy, pad

For example I have the following array:
`[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]`
what I want is
`[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]`

If the 1 is at the at the end, for example `[1, 0, 0, 0]` it should add only on one side `[1, 1, 0, 0]`

How do I add a 1 on either side while keeping the array the same length? I have looked at the numpy pad function, but that didn't seem like the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `numpy.convolve` with `mode == "same"`:

```
np.convolve([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1,1,1], "same")
```

Output:

```
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0])
```

With other examples:

```
np.convolve([1,0,0,0], [1,1,1], "same")
# array([1, 1, 0, 0])
np.convolve([0,0,0,1], [1,1,1], "same")
# array([0, 0, 1, 1])
np.convolve([1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0], [1,1,1], "same")
# array([1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.pad`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) to create two shifted copies of the array: one shifted 1 time toward the left (e.g. `0 1 0` -> `1 0 0`) and one shifted 1 time toward the right (e.g. `0 1 0` -> `0 0 1`).

Then you can add all three arrays together:

```
  0 1 0
  1 0 0
+ 0 0 1
-------
  1 1 1
```

Code:

```
output = a + np.pad(a, (1,0))[:-1] + np.pad(a, (0,1))[1:]
# (1, 0) says to pad 1 time at the start of the array and 0 times at the end
# (0, 1) says to pad 0 times at the start of the array and 1 time at the end
```

Output:

```
# Original array
>>> a = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])
>>> a
array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])

# New array
>>> output = a + np.pad(a, (1,0))[:-1] + np.pad(a, (0,1))[1:]
>>> output
array([1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0])
```

Comment: Thanks! This is an interesting technique, I think the convolve solution would be preferable in terms of code legibility, but this too is very helpful!